# Finding values greater than * in a map list

Tags: scala, list, search

My current system is a mapped String,List[Int], the String being a key value, "Sk1", "Sk2" etc, and the int is a list of numbers from 0-9.

Here is my current method to find all of the lists, how do I edit this to find only all of the "Sk*"s greater than the selected "SK*". The value of the list is the last element of the tail, which I already have a function to find. It is the handleFive option menu. To clarify, I need to find the last element (already have that function) then display only stocks greater than the selected stock.

Handler for the menu options

```
  def handleFive(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(currentStockLevel)
    true
  }

  def handleSeven(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowPointsForStock(allStockLevel)
    true
  }
```

Functions that invoke and interact with the user

```
// Returns a single result, not a list
  def mnuShowSingleDataStock(f: (String) => (String,Int)) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }

//Returns a list value
  def mnuShowPointsForStock(f: (String) => (String,List[Int])) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }
```

Not sure how to edit this, currently it shows ALL of the values in the list, I only want to return values greater than the selected value

```
  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def currentStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }

//Unsure how to change this to only return values greater than the selected one, not everything
  def currentStockLevel (stock: String): (String, List[Int]) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }
```

My current mapped list - THIS IS MAPDATA

```
val mapdata = Map(
    "SK1" -> List(9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1),
    "SK2" -> List(0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1),
    "SK3" -> List(8, 7, 1, 8, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 9, 7, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8, 1, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 3, 6, 8, 8, 7, 4, 0, 6),
    "SK4" -> List(2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8),
    "SK5" -> List(2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3),
    "SK6" -> List(2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9),
    "SK7" -> List(6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0),
    "SK8" -> List(2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6),
    "SK9" -> List(7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6)
  )
```

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I have updated the question to maybe make it understandable a bit more? If you wouldn't mind taking another look

Comment: If your stock is SK3, do you want to get the last element for each of SK4, SK5 ... to SK9, or all the elements in SK3 with values greater than the last element ?

Comment: If i select SK3 I want all the last elements for SK4, SK5, etc all that have a higher last value than the last value of SK3 @CyrilleCorpet

Comment: Do you also want last values for SK1 and SK2 (if they are greater) ? It does not change much for the code, but I'm just making sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Yeah, every other SK that is greater and the number,
So if i search SK1 ill get SK2 > 9, SK3>8 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Map[String, List[Int]]` type has a `filterKeys(f: String => Boolean)` method, in order to keep only the keys satisfying a given predicate.

A possible solution would be

```
// get int value from stock if of the form "SK<int>"
def stockInt(stock: String): Option[Int] = 
  Try(stock.drop(2).toInt).filter(_ => stock.startsWith("SK")).toOption

// we keep the keys in the return, so that you do not get unordered results
// (order is not assured by Map)
def currentStockLevel(stock: String): (String, Map[String, Int]) = {
  val maybeN = stockInt(stock)
  def isGreater(other: String) = (for {
    o <- stockInt(other)
    n <- maybeN
  } yield o > n).getOrElse(true) // if any key is not in the form of SK*, assume it is greater than the original stock

  (
    stock, 
    mapdata.filterKeys(isGreater(_)).mapValues(findLast(_))
  )
}
```

Another possibility, if you are sure to have only "SK" keys, is to use `SortedMap`, which uses a `SortedSet` for its keys, so that you are sure to have key-value pairs ordered as you want them to be.

In that case, a solution would be

```
//put all values in mapdata in a SortedMap
val sortedMap = SortedMap[String, List[Int]]() ++ mapdata

def currentStockLevel(stock: String): (String, List[Int]) = {
  (
    stock, 
    sortedMap.dropWhile(_ <= stock).toList.map(_._2).map(findLast(_))
  )
}
```

**EDIT** (after comments on what is expected as a return):

If I understand well what you are trying to do, you want to filter on the values rather than the keys. This is not a problem, `Map` also has a `filter(p: ((K, V)) => Boolean): Map[K, V]` method to do just that:

```
def currentHigherStockLevel(stock: String): Map[String, Int] = {
  val current = datamap.get(stock).map(findLast).getOrElse(0) // if stock is not in the keySet, we keep all keys, by keeping those greater than 0.
  datamap.mapValues(findLast).filter {
    case (sk, val) => val > current
  }
}
```

This returns a `Map[String; Int]` where the values are the last ones that are greater than the one given as parameter (we keep their keys because they will probably be useful).

Comment: My current system allows me to search for, say "SK1" and with the supplied code it returns the last item in the list, in this instance "1" so "SK1 > 1" is what is returned. I need to be able to search for "SK1" and instead of returning the last value, return all other last values from all the other lists that are greater than my searched for one

Answer (score 1):

If the key strings are things like `"SK9"` and `"SK10"` then you have to cut the digits out, convert to `Int`, and compare/filter them, but if your keys are kept in a completely consistent format: `"SK001"`, `"SK002"` ... `"SK009"`, `"SK010"` ... `"SK099"`, `"SK100"`, etc., then you use simple string comparisons to filter for just what you want.

```
mapdata.filterKeys(_ >= stock).values  // an Iterable[List[Int]]
```

Comment: I get the errror "Cannot resolve symbol "filterKeys"" when I try to use this method, any idea why?

Comment: The filterKeys is a method on `mapdata`, not on`mapdata.get(stock)`, which is an `Option[List[Int]]`.

Comment: Sorry, I inserted the suggested filter in  the wrong place.  It's not clear to me how you handle/return multiple results, but this is how to filter for them.

Comment: @jwvh Sorry I think I have asked this wrong, I search for, for instance, "SK2" and the result is the last int in the list, which would be "1" So my return would be "SK2 > 1"